# SQL Server : how to convert binary back to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, type-conversion, sql-convert

Admin of our IS stored 8 flags like '00010000' (only true and false) to SQL Server as `binary(2)`. In this format data has values like '0x1000'.

Is possible to convert this binary back to '00010000' ?

`Convert`, `Cast`, `Substring` don't work.

Comment: Is '0x1000' really the same value as '00010000'?

Comment: Yes. When I have values from IS '00010000' then in SQL is value '0x1000'. But if I have for example '00110000' then value is '0x3000'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query returns hexadecimal number (0x... - it is hexadecimal) as its bit mask

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    Test    VARBINARY(2)
)

INSERT #Temp
VALUES
    (0x1001),
    (0x3001),
    (0x5000),
    (0x6000),
    (0xf000),
    (0xf250)

SELECT *, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), Test, 2)
    , '0', '0000')
    , '1', '0001')
    , '2', '0010')
    , '3', '0011')
    , '4', '0100')
    , '5', '0101')
    , '6', '0110')
    , '7', '0111')
    , '8', '1000')
    , '9', '1001')
    , 'a', '1010')
    , 'b', '1011')
    , 'c', '1100')
    , 'd', '1101')
    , 'e', '1110')
    , 'f', '1111')
FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

`BINARY(2)` means 2 bytes, so 16 bits

0x3000 = '0011000000000000'

```
declare @v int = 0x3000

;WITH
T AS (  SELECT NULL N   UNION ALL   SELECT NULL ),
N as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T2.N) N
    FROM T T2, T T4, T T8, T T16
),
V AS (
    select N, POWER(2,N-1) P, CAST(@v as binary(2)) b2, @v V
    from N
),
B AS (
    SELECT N, B2, CAST((V/P) % 2 AS char(1)) B
    from V
)
SELECT B2, [16]+[15]+[14]+[13]+[12]+[11]+[10]+[9]+[8]+[7]+[6]+[5]+[4]+[3]+[2]+[1] BASE2
FROM B
PIVOT ( MIN(B) FOR N IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16]) ) P
```

output

```
B2      BASE2
0x3000  0011000000000000
```

Answer (score -1):

Your original data is most likely lost. When you convert a number to binary in SQL there is only a limited amount of "space" to store that data, the space is determined by the byte size of the field, in this case 2.

The issue occurs when the data is saved to the database, using a binary(2) means that data is truncated when saved, meaning that you have lost at least the 4 first "flags" in your data. (the 4 numbers at the start of your binary number).

for example, the below shows what SQL stores for the number 10010010 in binary 6, 4 and 2.

```
Binary(6) - 0x00000098BD9A
Binary(4) - 0x0098BD9A
Binary(2) - 0xBD9A
```

as you can see using binary 2 means you lose data from your number. That is gone and cannot be retrieved using the DB (unless you save transaction logs, which, given you have a DBA storing boolean values as an 8 bit block using a binary(2) field I doubt you have). So sorry to say this but you simply cannot do what you need to, and it's whoever thought using binary(2) for an 8 digit number was a good idea and then didn't test their decision that is to blame.

Comment: So there must be sometings else coded before inserting to sql if I get result '0x9200' when I test your example '10010010' ? That would explain why they are able to recover data to original 'array'.

Comment: If you have a program that is able to translate the stored values into the origional 8 digit value successfully 100% of the time then, yes, there must be a translation layer between the input and the database.

Comment: The 2 is 2 bytes not 2 bits