# How to convert binary to integer in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, binary-data

I have a binary code of 35 characters and have the expected output. Need the logic on how to convert that in SQL Server.

Input (binary): `00000110010110110001110101101110100` 
Expected output (int): `816570`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : how to convert binary back to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439509/sql-server-how-to-convert-binary-back-to-int)

Comment: @xXx no it doesn't help, I was looking for actual logic to be put in the function

Comment: What is the type of input? varbinary or a varchar containing zeros and ones?

Comment: Please read more about binary types :  https://sqlsunday.com/2017/01/09/binary-types/

Comment: The binary value for decimal value `816570` is `11000111010110111010‬`, so this is not exact conversion between decimal and binary values. If you can, post another couple of input-output values. Thanks.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759453/#77762910).

Answer (score 1):

Try below query using recursive CTE:

```
declare @bit varchar(50) = '00000110010110110001110101101110100'

;with cte as (
    select 0 [bit], cast(1 as bigint) powerOf2, substring(@bit, len(@bit) - 1, 1) [bitValue]
    union all
    select [bit] + 1, powerOf2 * 2, substring(@bit, len(@bit) - [bit] - 1, 1)
    from cte
    where [bit] + 1 < len(@bit)
)

select sum(powerOf2 * bitValue) from cte
```

It's important to make second column as `bigint`, so it can hold big integer values :)

Comment: Just ran your script and noticed it's different from the expected result? See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e27d27fc5150c665c44b27f5fe581cce)

Comment: @Birel But it's correct conversion, OP must have wrong output value or it is not binary representation of a number.